# a good 8086 emulator

Tags: macos, emulation, x86-16

is there a 8086 emulator for mac. If yes, which is the best

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What do you want the emulator for?

Comment: writing really simple programs, should be able to see all the registers n stuff

Comment: write it yourself! It's a good programming excercise :)

Comment: Why do you want to write 8086 programs?  The chip is mostly obsolete, and if you're looking for something of the period to write assembler programs in the 68000 is a whole lot more pleasant.

Comment: It's probably for an undergrad course on micro-processors

Answer (score 4):

Unless you need real raw 8086 (with custom OS) you should try:

DosBox!

Works nice for me!

Answer (score 2):

What about [this](http://i8086emu.sourceforge.net/) one? It's cross-platform and seems quite easy to use.. I suppose it's programmed with ncurses..

Comment: I don't see an OS X version...

Comment: @Martin: There are sources so you just need to compile them, as with many free software around. Ncurses version will work without any additional library but you'll need GTK2 for the graphical version.

Answer (score 2):

Try [QEMU](http://www.qemu.org/).  It is easily intalled via [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You should try http://seksen.sourceforge.net
It's a simple JAR file that seems to does the job pretty well! :-)

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you so much

Comment: @Razetime happy to help! Got me through college :)

Answer (score 0):

emu8086_4.08 is the most full featured 8086 emulator

Answer (score -1):

mame most likely has an 8086 emulator that you can borrow.