# 8086 emulator for mac OSX

Tags: macos, emulation, x86-16

I want to study about 8086 instructions. I want to know how the registers, flags, stack pointer etc are changing according to each instructions. So that I want to install an 8086 emulator in my Mac OS. Can anyone suggest me some options?

I have installed dosBox and checked it. But I cant find a way to see the register values, flags etc..

If there is no such emulator please suggest me some good tutorials. I want to know , how the segment registers(ES, CS, DS, SS, IP), general purpose registers(AX, BX, CX,DX, SP,BP, SI, DI), and all the flags(OF, DF,IF,TF, ZF,SF, AF, PF,CF) are changing according to each instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Both QEMU and Bochs can be used for Mac OSx.

(Never tried this on my own, but projects are really good)

Comment: thanks for the help. I've checked it. But I dont think there is a way to see the registers instantly when an instruction is executing.

Comment: Have you seen this question?


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216966/a-good-8086-emulator?rq=1

Comment: page not found (EMU8086 ziplib.com/emu8086) for this

Comment: @jjpp: GDB's `layout reg` TUI mode can show registers change as you single-step.  I hope BOCHS's built-in debugger has a similar feature.  (BOCHS is great for osdev stuff, where it can single-step the whole machine, parse GDT / page tables to let you double-check you have the right stuff there, and unlike GDB-remote + QEMU, BOCHS's debugger is aware of segmentation.)